# Changing href url in bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

Have a nice day. How I can change url in bootstrap modal? I making confirmation dialog with yii bootstrap extension. I have list of buttons with different on action url.

Buttons code

```
foreach ($Users as $a)
    {
                     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                        'label'=>Yii::t('default-ui', 'Remove'),
                        'type'=>'action', 
                        'icon'=>'trash',
                    'size'=>'mini', 
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                            'data-toggle'=>'modal',
                                'data-target'=>'#myModal',
)));

};
```

Modal form code:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal')); ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4>Removing user</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p>You really want remove this user?</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php 
         $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'inverse',
        'label'=>'Cancel',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); 
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'danger',
        'label'=>'Yes, remove',
        //'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('users/remove', array('id'=>$a['id'])), // here should be dynamic link for removing profile
    )); 
?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('#view_more')
      .removeData('modal')
      .modal({
        remote: someURL, //your url
        show: false
      });
```

A small demo
[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp3WY/70/)

Comment: Buttons creating in cycle:
    foreach ($Users as $a) // Users array: 'id'=>num, 'name'=>username
    {
       // Creating buttons 
    }

Comment: okk so url will be dynamic i guess?? and does that url contain id and username?

Comment: Yep, changing only `id`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
      'buttonType'=>'link',
      'url'=> array("/users/remove/{$a['id']}"),
      'type'=>'danger',
      'label'=>'Yes, remove',
      )); ?>
```